# How to add Values to NSObject Model Variables in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, model, viewcontroller, nsobject

I have created separate **NSObject class** called **ProfileModel**

like below:

```
class ProfileModel  : NSObject, NSCoding{

var userId : String!
var phone : String!
var firstName : String!
var email : String!
var profileImageUrl : String!
var userAddresses : [ProfileModelUserAddress]!

// Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
    userId = dictionary["userId"] as? String
    phone = dictionary["phone"] as? String
    firstName = dictionary["firstName"] as? String
    email = dictionary["email"] as? String
    profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as? String
}
/**
 * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
 */
func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]
{
    var dictionary = [String:Any]()
    if userId != nil{
        dictionary["userId"] = userId
    }
    if phone != nil{
        dictionary["phone"] = phone
    }
    if firstName != nil{
        dictionary["firstName"] = firstName
    }
    if email != nil{
        dictionary["email"] = email
    }
    if profileImageUrl != nil{
        dictionary["profileImageUrl"] = profileImageUrl
    }
    return dictionary
}

/**
 * NSCoding required initializer.
 * Fills the data from the passed decoder
 */
@objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    userId = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userId") as? String
    userType = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "userType") as? String
    phone = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "phone") as? String
    firstName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "firstName") as? String
    email = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "email") as? String
    profileImageUrl = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "profileImageUrl") as? String
}
/**
 * NSCoding required method.
 * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
 */
@objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
{
    if userId != nil{
        aCoder.encode(userId, forKey: "userId")
    }
    if phone != nil{
        aCoder.encode(phone, forKey: "phone")
    }
    if firstName != nil{
        aCoder.encode(firstName, forKey: "firstName")
    }
    if email != nil{
        aCoder.encode(email, forKey: "email")
    }
    if profileImageUrl != nil{
        aCoder.encode(profileImageUrl, forKey: "profileImageUrl")
    }

}
}
```

**In RegistrationViewController I adding firstName value which i need to show in ProfileViewController How ?**

In RegistrationViewController i am adding `firstName and phone` values which i need in ProfileViewController:

```
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: FloatingTextField!
var userModel : ProfileModel?

override func viewDidLoad() {
     let userID: String=jsonObj?["userId"] as? String ?? ""
     self.userModel?.firstName = self.firstNameTextField.text
      self.userModel?.phone = phoneTextField.text
}
}
```

This is ProfileViewController here in `name and number` i am not getting firstName and phone values why?:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var number: UILabel!
var userModel : ProfileModel? 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    name.text = userModel?.firstName
    number.text = userModel?.phone
}

}
```

PLease help me with code.

Comment: How do you pass the model instance between the two view controllers?

Comment: @Paulw11, shall i pass like this ` var userModel = ProfileModel()`

Comment: @Paulw11, how to add f`irstNameTextField.text` value to `userModel?.firstName` please do help

Comment: Have you actually created an instance of `ProfileModel` anywhere?  You need to create an instance and then pass that instance to the second view controller.

Comment: @Paulw11 could you please show me how to create instance and pass data

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set firstName or phone to the userModal which is nil. First you should create an instance, and then you can pass it through your controllers. We should change code step by step:

```
class ProfileModel {
    var userId : String?
    var phone : String?
    var firstName : String?
    var email : String?
    var profileImageUrl : String?
    var userAddresses : [ProfileModelUserAddress]?

    init() {}
}
```

Second, you need to reach ProfileModel instance from both of your ViewController classes. For this, you can create a singleton class:

```
class ProfileManager {
    static var shared = ProfileManager()

    var userModel: ProfileModel?

    private init() {}
}
```

Then you can reach it from both of your ViewControllers:

```
class RegistrationViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: FloatingTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let userModel = ProfileModel()
        userModel.firstName = self.firstNameTextField.text
        ProfileManager.shared.userModel = userModel
    }
}
```

Other VC:

```
class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var name: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let userModel = ProfileManager.shared.userModel,
            let firstName = userModel.firstName {
            name.text = firstName
        }
    }
}
```

Modify it as you wanted.